# Erro de tipagem ao receber chave estrangeira do banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql

Boa noite, basicamente essa é uma lista que fiz para mostrar os dados que foram inseridos no banco de dados, porém venho encontrando problemas de tipagem nas linhas 1 e 2 (marcados como comentário), como previsto, a função getstring só funcionaria com strings, porém preciso receber "cidade_nomecidade" e "doenca_nomedoenca" (da coluna no banco de dados) que são do tipo Cidade e Doenca. Há alguma forma de eu conseguir dar algum get nessas chaves estrangeiras dentro desse contexto ? O erro gerado é: "incompatible types:String cannot be converted to Cidades"

```
public List<Casos> read(){
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Casos> caso = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM casos");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            Casos casos = new Casos();
            casos.setIdcaso(rs.getInt("idcaso"));
            casos.setQtdCaso(rs.getInt("qtdCaso"));
            casos.setCidades(rs.getstring(("cidade_nomecidade")); //LINHA 1
            casos.setDoenca(rs.getString("doenca_nomedoenca")); //LINHA 2
            caso.add(casos);
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha na leitura");
    }finally{

        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);

    }


    return caso;

}

public class Casos {

private int     idcaso;
private int     qtdCaso;
private Doenca  doenca;
private Cidades cidades;

public Doenca getDoenca() {
    return doenca;
}

public void setDoenca(Doenca doenca) {
    this.doenca = doenca;
}

public Cidades getCidades() {
    return cidades;
}

public void setCidades(Cidades cidades) {
    this.cidades = cidades;
}

public int getQtdCaso() {
    return qtdCaso;
}

public void setQtdCaso(int qtdCaso) {
    this.qtdCaso = qtdCaso;
}

public int getIdcaso() {
    return idcaso;
}

public void setIdcaso(int idcaso) {
    this.idcaso = idcaso;
}
```

}

Comment: Olha.. se o tipo do conteúdo no banco é texto... você deve utilizar o `getString()` e ajustar os seus setters para construir o objeto que espera

Comment: Você deve pegar a chave dos objetos Cidade e chamar a DAO para carregá-la também, ou se só precisar do Id instanciar e setar o Id

Comment: O MySQL não permite criar tipos, então essas colunas não podem ser do tipo que você está falando.  A primeira coisa que precisa fazer é definir corretamente o que está fazendo.

Comment: Além do que o @Maniero falou, sua linha 1  `casos.setCidades(rs.getstring(("cidade_nomecidade"));` está com o `getstring` (com o 'S' do String) minúsculo.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe tipo `Cidade` e `Doenca` no banco de dados, e sim no código Java. O que o erro está dizendo é que você está pegando uma string, que é o resultado de `rs.getString("cidade_nomecidade")` e está tentando colocá-la num objeto Cidade com o  `caso.setCidades()`.

"cidade_nomecidade" e "doenca_nomedoenca" são as chaves estrangeiras para as tabelas cidade e doenca.

Então, por exemplo, você tem 3 tabelas, com as seguintes colunas:

- casos: idCaso (int), qtdCaso (int), cidade_nomecidade (String), doenca_nomedoenca (String)
- cidade: nomecidade(String), estado(String)
- doenca: nomedoenca(String), prioridade(int)

Para preencher o objeto Java `Caso` você precisa fazer uma consulta sql que pegue os dados das três tabelas, usando um join:

```
select * from casos
inner join cidade on cidade_nomecidade = nomecidade
inner join doenca on doenca_nomedoenca = nomedoenca
```

E então criar o objeto caso, e os objetos cidade e doenca a partir dos dados retornados:

```
Caso caso = new Caso();
caso.setIdCaso(rs.getInt("idCaso"));
caso.setQtdCaso(rs.getInt("qtdCaso"));

Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
cidade.setNome(rs.getString(("nomecidade"));
cidade.setEstado(rs.getString(("estado"));
caso.setCidade(cidade);

Doenca doenca = new Doenca();
doenca.setNome(rs.getString(("nomedoenca"));
doenca.setPrioridade(rs.getInt(("prioridade"));
caso.setDoenca(doenca);

casos.add(caso);
```

Observação: se possível troque esse nomes de classes, atributos, variáveis e tabelas para o singular. Só `List<Caso> casos` deveria estar no plural.
Também é preferível usar números para os identificadores e chaves estrangeiras, e objetos (e.g. Integer e Long ao invés de int e long) no Java. Por exemplo:

- casos: idCaso (Long), qtdCaso (Long), cidade_id (Long), doenca_id (Long)
- cidade: id(Long), nome(String)
- doenca: id(Long), nomedoenca(String), prioridade(Integer)